# Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android

Kindly help me, I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution of this error.

**build.gragle:**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'leadtrak'
                keyPassword 'leadtrak1'
                storeFile file('/home/sheraz/AndroidStudioProjects/LeadTrak/LeadTrack/docs/LeadTrakKeyStore.jks')
                storePassword 'leadtrak1'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "leadtrak.activities"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 9
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'


            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }

    }


    dependencies {

        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile files('libs/acra-4.4.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
        compile files('libs/ksoap2.jar')
        compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
        compile files('libs/twilioclient-android.jar')
        compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.1.jar')
    }
```

**Error log:**

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$1) that doesn't
>   come with an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class
>   was probably produced by a Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly Error:indicate that it is
>   *not* an inner class. Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$1)
>   that doesn't come with an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute.
>   This class was probably produced by a Error:compiler that did not
>   target the modern .class file format. The recommended Error:solution
>   is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly Error:indicate that it is
>   *not* an inner class. Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$2)
>   that doesn't come with an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute.
>   This class was probably produced by a Error:compiler that did not
>   target the modern .class file format. The recommended Error:solution
>   is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly Error:indicate that it is
>   *not* an inner class. Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$2) that doesn't come
>   with an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was
>   probably produced by a Error:compiler that did not target the modern
>   .class file format. The recommended Error:solution is to recompile the
>   class from source, using an up-to-date compiler Error:and without
>   specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   incorrectly Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.zip.ZipEngine$1) that doesn't come with
>   an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably
>   produced by a Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class
>   file format. The recommended Error:solution is to recompile the class
>   from source, using an up-to-date compiler Error:and without specifying
>   any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring Error:this
>   warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class. Error:The number of
>   method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to
>   resolve this issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit
> >     value 2

Comment: Is this complete buid.gradle?

Comment: yes this is complete. @Haroon

Comment: You got answer  from @Vivek Mishra

Comment: Is your problem solved.

Comment: Yes my problem solved. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is your main problem

> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

To solve this put the following lines in your **app level gradle file**.

Put this line in **defaultConfig** block

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And add the following **dependencies**

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

After this rebuild your project. Hopefully this should resolve your error.

And try avoiding **+** symbol while adding dependencies in your project as you are doing with play services dependencies

To remove **OutOfMemory error** add this inside your `android block` in app level gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. after trying your solution i am getting this error. 

Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Thank you very much :) Solved my problem

Comment: very nice answer. Note `incremental true` is deprecated and can be commented out

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace and check

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "leadtrak.activities"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
        dexOptions {
     javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

     }

     signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'leadtrak'
            keyPassword 'leadtrak1'
            storeFile file('/home/sheraz/AndroidStudioProjects/LeadTrak/LeadTrack/docs/LeadTrakKeyStore.jks')
            storePassword 'leadtrak1'
        }
    }

     buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-   android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'


        }
    }

   dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile files('libs/twilioclient-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: I am unable to find difference between this and my gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error similar to this when checking out a project from SVN

what caused it was when SVN finished the check out Android Studio asked if i wanted to create it as a project - and I clicked yes , turns out it already was a project and trying to make it a project within a project broke Gradle's ability to build it - but checking the project out and just opening the folder worked for me